# PHP imap , fails to connect

Tags: php, openssl, imap

I get the following response when attempting to connect to imap server, using tls and self-sighned certificate.

> Connection error: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)

the Imap open is the following

```
$mailbox = new ImapMailbox('{mail.NNNNNN.com:143}', 'YYY@NNNN.com', 'IIIII');
```

I can't really understand from where this error is coming from , if though i installed locally the server certificate it still fails.

i added `{mail.NNNNN.com:143}/INBOX` but it still doesnt seem it can connect.

---

**edited**

after setting up stunnel it logs the following information

- 2015.11.09 16:02:14 LOG5[2]: Service [imapsrv] accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:8848
- 2015.11.09 16:02:14 LOG5[2]: s_connect: connected NNN.NN.NN.NN:143
- 2015.11.09 16:02:14 LOG5[2]: Service [imapsrv] connected remote server from 192.168.1.73:8849
- 2015.11.09 16:02:14 LOG3[2]: SSL_connect: 1408F10B: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
- 2015.11.09 16:02:14 LOG5[2]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to SSL, 0 byte(s) sent to socket

Comment: Well, "wrong version number" suggests that the two end points can't agree on a protocol version. Can you confirm that the IMAP server uses an SSL version compatible with the compiled version of the imap extension?  If you don't have admin access to the server, [you can probe](http://superuser.com/a/224263/362931)

Comment: Wrong version number because you're connecting the plaintext port.  143 is unencrypted IMAP.

Comment: @Max i tried connecting with Thunderbird that autodetects configuration, it connects to port `143`

Comment: @bishop i runned an nmap scan not sure what kind of information is useful can you take a look http://pastie.org/10540856

Comment: Alright, well, your server setup appears good.  Instruct the imap extension you want to use SSL.  Try: `new ImapMailbox('{mail.NNNNNN.com:143/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'user@examp.le', '***');`

Comment: @bishop i finally managed to connect using `/imap/tls/novalidate-cert/user=test.group` after `/tls/novalidate-cert/user=test` it kept throwing authentication failures i added the group `user=test.group` then it connected , too bad that php imap doesn't seem to have many debug options so it could output meaningful messages.

Comment: Glad you got it working!